# What's wrong in creating/printing this array?

Tags: bash, timestamps, array, arithmetic

To find the average time taken to create certain files, I'm using this minutes array, then would simply use bash arithmetic to find the average. However, I'm unable to get the difference except for the first pair of elements. Here `l` is the array of subtractions of the `i++` and `i`; what's wrong?

```
MMarray=(`ls -lrt /some/location/ |tail -57|head -55|tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f8|cut -c4,5`)
arrLen=`echo ${#MMarray[@]}`

for((i=0;i<$arrLen;i++))
do
    x=$(($i+1))
    j=${MMarray[x]#0}
    k=${MMarray[i]#0}
    l=($(($j-$k)))
    echo ${l[$i]}
done
```

Also, how would `02-59` subtraction be handled?

Comment: Leading zero are interpreted as octal in bash. So while `02-59` is  OK. `08 - 59` would crash. (And e.g. `020` would be decimal `16`.) To specify base one can say `base#number`, e.g. `(( 10#08 ))` or `(( 10#$some_var ))`.

Comment: Also  note that you can say `(( x = i + 1 ))` instead of `x=$(($i + 1))`.

Comment: Also note that you can say `arrLen=${#MMarray[@]}`. (No need for `echo`.)

Comment: Which is the sole reason I had to put the `#0` at the end of the variables `j` and `k`, thanks though! What Im unable to comprehend is how come the length of array `l` is being 1, as I've already put the `( )`, need to print all the differences, could see the differences are being calculated if put `set -ex` in script, unable to store/print :(

Comment: To append to the array say `((l[i] = j - k))` or `l[i]=$(( j - k ))` or `l+=( $(( j - k )) )` – for the latest you have to declare the array before the loop, as in: `l=()`, or `declare -a l=()`. The *declare* specifically set it as a non-associative array. If you use `declare -A` the array becomes associative - but then the keys are also in random order, i.e. if you say `for k in ...`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know times are not much over one hour, you can simply add 60 if the result is negative. However, this is not the way to do it anyway. There are several points I'd like to raise:

1. NEVER parse output of ls, especially not the time part. It depends on the locale and can give completely unpredictable results.
2. Why assume times are around a hour and just like at the minutes, if you can just subtract dates? Use the unix timestamp - the number of second since the beginning of the world (1970). That's the standard way of storing time.
3. Just write `let i++` and `let l=j-k`, don't use millions of parentheses
4. You are making `$l` an array of length 1, and then access `$i` th member. This is why it only works for the first pair.
5. You are using very c-like programming style. Use a loop of the form `for i in "${MMarray[@]}"; do...` and just save the previous one.
6. You are using too much arrays and loops, do everything in a stream of dates, it will be much better. So pretty much everything can be rewritten.
7. You do realize, that an average time is simply first minus last divided by the number of files minus 1 (the number of diffences)? You don't need to subtract and then add together again...

What to do if you want to get all the time differences in seconds, one per line:

```
find /some/location -type f -name '*your filter which files you want*' -printf '%T@\n' | sort -n | awk 'NR>1 { print  $1-previous } {previous = $1}'
```

What it does? `find` finds the files and prints the unix timestamps. If you don't specify `-name` it lists eveything. `-type f` means only files, no directories. `sort -n` sorts the times numerically. `awk` simply computes and prints differences.

For average, just keep the first and the last date. For instance, for all the files in the current directory:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@\n' | sort -n | awk 'NR==1 { first = $1 } END{ print ($1-first)/(NR-1) }'
```

The results are decimal numbers in seconds, but you can easily just write `int(($1-first)/(NR-1))` for an integer or `int(($1-first)/(NR-1))/60` for minutes.

Comment: Would be grateful! Array's range is [0-60], also negative subtractions are rare, as for the #5 It works, aint it? The data I've is just `HH:MM` of these files last modified timestamps in `ls -lrt` so how would literally subtracting dates would help is unclear, please enlighten, also, is it possible to convert all `HH:MM` to epoch seconds, that would help a lot as then it just would need `/` & `%` with sixties.

Comment: Don't convert anything by hand, just give `--time-style +%s` argument to `ls` to get epoch, if you really want to do it this way. If you really only have `HH:MM` then just do `let minutes+=hours*60` and after that do the subtraction. If you get negative numbers, just do `if [ $difference -lt 0 ]; then let difference+=60; fi` (or 1440 if you already added the hours*60).

Still... average difference is last minus first divided by the number of differences, so all this is unnecessary.

Comment: There were actually three types of these .prop files, which would be generating randomly, however older run's files will still be there in same location, so calculating average time for all of these three kinds of files would be little difficult as `ls -lrt kind-name.prop` would be having older files too which can't be considered.

Comment: That's why you give a glob pattern, something like `-iname myfile*.prop` or whatever. Or you can still squeeze `tail` and `head` between `find` and `sort` like you did before. And if you really want, you can still use `ls` and all that cutting and translating and pasting instead of `find` and keep the awk script. Also, I really recommend epoch times and sorting - who says the files were really generated alphabetically?